# Preventing the python and ffmpeg heroku buildpacks from overwriting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: python, heroku, path, ffmpeg, libmemcached

I'm deployng a Django app to heroku, which requires ffmpeg. To accomplish this I am using [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to install both [heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg](https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg) and [heroku-buildpack-python](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python), and all of that works fine. The problem is my that app also depends on `django-pylibmc-sasl`, `python-memcached`, `pylibmc` et al. which, as per usual, heroku senses and automatically installs `libmemcached` for me.

Here's where something goes a little wrong. If I remove the custom buildpack everything runs fine (except for ffmpeg obviously). As soon as I add it in, however, while I can run `ffmpeg`, python fails on `import pylibmc` (or rather on `import _pylibmc` inside the module itself). After a amount of head-scratching I decided to have a look at the environment variables, here's what I got:

**With only the Python buildpack enabled:**

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib
```

**With both the Python and the ffmpeg buildpacks enabled:**

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:vendor/ffmpeg/lib
```

It looks like one or both of the buildpacks simply overwrites the other, or avoids setting the variable should it be already set. The ffmpeg buildpack seems to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in [a way that looks kosher to me](https://github.com/shunjikonishi/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg/blob/master/bin/compile#L23), while the Python buildpack does [a few](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/utils#L66) [things](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/compile#L43) that I don't really understand the reason for.

### Solution

Anyway, after manually overriding the library path using `heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:vendor/ffmpeg/lib` I am able to use both `libmemcached` and `ffmpeg`, but it doesn't feel too robust. What if something changes in one of the buildpacks path settings, or I add another buildpack - then I would have to manually edit the library path variable.

### Better solution?

So, while this is not really an urgent question at all, I simply would like to know:

- Is there a better way of solving this issue?
- Might I have made some configuration error leading up to the path conflict?
- Should this be considered a bug in either of the buildpacks?

Comment: Issue reported [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/124).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance at the code this may be an issue with `heroku-buildpack-python`. Look at your `~/.profile` (`heroku run bash`) and look where `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set. My guess is you'll see `ffmpeg`'s first, and then see Python's setting overriding it.

If that's the case you should file a bug.

Comment: Thanks, good idea! That yields `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:vendor/ffmpeg/lib"` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-/app/.heroku/vendor/lib}`. So it seems `heroku-buildpack-python ` will only set the library path if it is not already set.

Comment: Yep. Seems like a bug in `heroku-buildpack-python`, you should tell them. By the way: I don't know `heroku-buildpack-multi`, but if you can specify the *order* in which the different buildpacks run then you have a temporary workaround: run `buildpack-python` first.

Comment: I think the order in the `.buildpacks` file does specify the order in which buildpacks are loaded, but I got the same results none the less. I think buildpacks themselves can run code at different stages of compilation/setup, which is probably why changing the order did not work. I'll create a bug report. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, scratch that. Installation generates `ffmpeg.sh` and `python.sh` in side `~/.profile.d/`. The [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/profiled) says _"Scripts in the `.profile.d/` directory will be executed in an arbitrary order"_.